# Python Scraping Html Trouble

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape my internet providers data usage. I tried looking for an api of sorts but they don't have one. I am resorting to scraping the html whch looks like this

```
</tr><tr class="top-border"><td>17&nbsp;&nbsp;Monday</td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>2,991.69&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>2.92&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>1,232.04&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>1.20&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>4,223.73&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>4.12&nbsp;GB</span></td>         <td>
            <div class="progress"><div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 51%;"></div></div>         </td>

        </tr><tr><td>18&nbsp;&nbsp;Tuesday</td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>3,589.42&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>3.51&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>1,199.58&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>1.17&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>4,789.00&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>4.68&nbsp;GB</span></td>           <td>
            <div class="progress"><div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 57%;"></div></div>         </td>
```

ect

I tried to use pythons re.search but I can only get a bit of info out of it.
eg:

```
search = re.search("class='gb'>(.*)&nbsp;GB</span>",raw_info)
for i in range(0,100):
    try:
        print(search.group(i))
    except:
        break
```

output:

```
class='gb'>6.88&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>
1,295.90&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>1.27&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='
text-right'><span class='mb'>8,340.12&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>8.14&nbsp;G
B</span>
6.88&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'><span class='mb'>1,295.90&nb
sp;MB</span><span class='gb'>1.27&nbsp;GB</span></td></td><td class='text-right'
><span class='mb'>8,340.12&nbsp;MB</span><span class='gb'>8.14
```

I learned I can't use groups like that to print out all of the numbers

tldr:
I need to print all the numbers referring to gb and print them like this

> 2.92,1.20,4.12
>
> 3.51,1.17,4.68

Comment: Word of advice, never use regex on HTML. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it's a very flexible library which can do exactly what you are looking for.

```
html = scraped
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'gb'})
```

You will then have a list of all the `span` tags that have the `gb` class. Producing the numbers and converting them to floats then applying whatever format you want to print them in is fairly simple.